# iOS (Swift): Dimming UIButton when pressed

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` subclass that is generated as follows:

```
class MoreOptionsButton: UIButton {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect)
        UIColor.red.setFill()
        path.fill()

        let r = CGRect(x: rect.width * 0.5 - rect.width * 0.15 * 0.5, y: rect.height * 0.5 - rect.height * 0.15 * 0.5, width: rect.width * 0.15, height: rect.height * 0.15)
        var circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: r)
        UIColor.white.setFill()
        circlePath.fill()

        circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: r.offsetBy(dx: -rect.width / 4.0, dy: 0.0))
        UIColor.white.setFill()
        circlePath.fill()

        circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: r.offsetBy(dx: rect.width / 4.0, dy: 0.0))
        UIColor.white.setFill()
        circlePath.fill()

    }

}
```

and looks like this:

[image]

However, when I press down on this button in the simulator it does not automatically dim like a normal `System` type button would. **How do I achieve this effect, please?**

Comment: This is a rather complicated way to create a button. Ideally, you should just use an image.

Comment: @Sulthan Yes - but you don't have to worry about 2x, 3x etc. this way.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can use only @3x and it will still look good (any iOS exporter will care of all 3 anyway). The important part is that image is a faster solution, without code that needs maintenance and a different image can be swapped in easily when needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add below code in your UIButton custom class:

```
override var isHighlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
        alpha = isHighlighted ? 0.4 : 1
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can also check that directly in `draw` and change the `.red` color to something else. The effect of transparency depends too much on the background.

Comment: @Alex Welcome. Happiee coding :)

Answer (score 0):

there are two states of button selected and unselected state you can assign images for both of the states.